# Jquery to setTimeout()

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate, settimeout

I have code from web (https://codepen.io/aleksander-koty/pen/yEgxVg)

start animation From two lettes C T
 end animation:  Caaa Taana (all text)

but i dont want open-text with scroll oh no no no ..
 I want create animation to 3 sec. after 3 sec. text should be again change    to two letters. Must be done only once, not loop.

How to write this in JAVASCRIPT OR JQUERY

if you're so kind. I will be very grateful. This help will affect my practices very much

I have code :

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  var text = $(".text");
  var textT = $(".textT");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 200) {
      text.removeClass("hidden");
      textT.removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      text.addClass("hidden");
      textT.addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="text hidden">
  <li>C</li>
  <li class="ghost">a</li>
  <li class="ghost">a</li>
  <li class="ghost">a</li>
  <li class="ghost">a</li>
</ul>
<ul class="textT hidden">
  <li>C</li>
  <li class="ghost">v</li>
  <li class="ghost">v</li>
  <li class="ghost">a</li>
  <li class="ghost">a</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,700');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 200vh;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
.text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.textT {
  position: fixed;
  top: 56%;
  left: 47%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 0;
}




.text.hidden {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.textT.hidden {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.text li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 2em;
}

.textT li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 2em;
}


.text.hidden li.spaced {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.text li.spaced {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.text.hidden li.ghost {
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
}



.textT.hidden li.spaced {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.textT li.spaced {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.textT.hidden li.ghost {
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DELETE PLEASE..
solution is :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var text = $(".text");
      var textT = $(".textT");
  setTimeout(function() {
    text.removeClass("hidden");
    textT.removeClass("hidden");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    text.addClass("hidden");
    textT.addClass("hidden");
  }, 9000); 
});
```